# DigitalOcean Apache 2 Debian 7 Virtual Host for subdomain

Tags: apache, dns, apache2, apache2.2

I have VPS on digitalocean.com. To DNS for example.com I added cname subdomain.

Server work on Debian 7 with apache 2.2 and php 5.5

I have problem with subdomain configuration. I tried all tutorial form first 4 google pages for "apache subdomain configuration".

But still after request subdomain.example.com response is example.com content.

I use:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

Result is:

```
    apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Thu Nov 28 15:58:58 2013] [warn] VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:80 overlaps with VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:80, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive
[Thu Nov 28 15:58:58 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
VirtualHost configuration:
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:80     subdomain.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/subdomain.example.com:1)
127.0.0.1:80           xxx.xxx.xx.xxx (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:80      example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com:1)
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com I have link i sites-enabled

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:80>
  ServerName  example.com
  ServerAdmin email@email.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

  <Directory /var/www/example.com>
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.html5
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  ErrorDocument 404 /404/

  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|ico|png)$ \ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ \no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary

  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sotes-available/subdomain.example.com I have link in sites-enabled

```
:80>
  ServerName  subdomain.example.com
  ServerAdmin mail@mail.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.example.com
 ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
  <Directory /var/www/subdomain.example.com>
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.html5
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  ErrorDocument 404 /404/

  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|ico|png)$ \ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ \no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary

  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

</VirtualHost>
```

I tried too with ServerAlias, foledrs in /var/www have owner as www-data and 755 chmod.

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

as you can see in your 2nd block, you are missing the this:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:80>
```

and that should be configured at the beginning. you need to have your server's fully qualified domain name by doing this:
if you use root as user, then:
nano /etc/hosts

then add this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

#Virtual Hosts 
12.34.56.789    example.com
```

then save it and restart Apache, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is adding subdomain record to your domain you assigned. to do so, follow the tutorial on their site at: [How To Set Up and Test DNS Subdomains with DigitalOcean's DNS Panel](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-and-test-dns-subdomains-with-digitalocean-s-dns-panel)